# Is there a way to automatically increment the Version value in the Config.esriaddinx file?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in

I don't think there is an out-of-the-esri-box way to do this, but has anyone hacked up a way to change this value automatically for a build? Perhaps using a pre-build event command?

Comment: +1! `Date` would be good too.

Comment: How about using some Python in the pre-build event to edit the XML directly?

Comment: @ChadCooper: I ended up going that route. I was really hoping someone would have already written it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python option works for me:

`c:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\python.exe C:\sandbox\py\misc\UpdateAddInVersionNumber.py "$(ProjectDir)Config.esriaddinx"`

[image]

*(Python gurus, feel free to jump in and make it better)*
UpdateAddInVersionNumber.py:

```
import os, sys
import xml.dom.minidom
import datetime

filename = sys.argv[1]
print filename

b = 0

doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(filename)

tags = doc.getElementsByTagName('Version')

if (len(tags)==1):
    currentNodeValue =  tags[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    tokens = currentNodeValue.split('.')
    lastToken = tokens[len(tokens) -1]
    if lastToken.isnumeric():
        i = int(lastToken)
        i +=1       
        tokens[len(tokens) -1] = str(i)
        newVersionNumberValue='.'.join(tokens)
        tags[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = newVersionNumberValue
        b = 1
        print newVersionNumberValue


tags = doc.getElementsByTagName('Date')
if (len(tags)==1):
    tags[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue =datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    b = 1
    print tags[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

if (b==1):
    f = open(filename,'wb')
    doc.writexml(f,encoding= 'utf-8')
    f.close()

sys.exit()
```

Comment: You should get extra points for having to roll this yourself!

Comment: Heck of a lot better then my method! I've installed cygwin with sed that does roughly the same thing. Kudos!

Comment: @baens: that's what I attempted initially, but I'm terrible with sed/ssed!

Answer (score 0):

A second approach using a utility exe (requires .NET 4) that I've recently extended:

`esri_addin_util.exe -o UpdateProperties --updateDate --addinDesc="Test Description ABC" --increaseVersion  -f "Path to the Directory containing the esriaddinx file"`

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cumminsjp/misc/esri_addin_util.zip

```
  -o/--operation required option is missing.


  -f, --file           Add In File

  -o, --operation      Required. Operation: ShowAddInVersion, PurgeAddIns,
                       Diag, ZipAddIn, UpdateProperties

  --output             Output file

  --updateDate         (Default: True) Updates the Date property of the AddIn
                       to the current UTC date when performing a '-o
                       UpdateProperties' operation.

  --addinDesc          Updates the AddIn Description.

  --increaseVersion    (Default: True) Increases the version number of the
                       AddIn when performing a '-o UpdateProperties' operation.

  --help               Display this help screen.
```