# Versioning an ArcMap Extension

Tags: arcmap, extensions, version-control

When developing an ArcMap extension, is there an automatic way to handle versioning?

In the snippet below, the Version tag can be updated manually, but is there a way to auto-increment it or let the build process version it?

```xml
<ESRI.Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>MyExtension</Name>
  <AddInID>{...}</AddInID>
  <Description>My Extension</Description>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Image>Images\MyExtension.png</Image>
  <Date>13/03/2013</Date>
  <Targets>
    <Target name="Desktop" version="10.0" />
  </Targets>
  <AddIn language="CLR4.0" library="MyExtension.dll" namespace="MyExtension">
  </AddIn>
</ESRI.Configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking to build an extension and not an add-in as your code suggests?

Comment: For AddIns, see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15422/31

Comment: Indeed I meant AddIn instead of Extension. Thanks @Jay Cummins. That will help.